# Using custom templates for Angular select box

Tags: angularjs, select

I have to allow users to select a person from a list. The problem is that I need to show some extra information (gender, age, occupation) for each person in the list, but when selected I should show only the first and last name. For technical reasons I must use select box, not bootstrap drop-down. I have been looking for a solution for hours, but so far could not come up with anything. Is it even possible, anyone knows?

Answer (score 1):

Use [ng-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions), and delegate to a function to generate the representation of the person:

```
<select ng-options="p as toOption(p) for p in persons" ng-model="selectedPerson">
</select>
```

In the toOption() function, test if `p` (the person passed as argument) is the selected one (i.e. is `selectedPerson`), and return the appropriate representation accordingly.

Here's a [demo plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/HLPPkEXoYpM7nFNcemoX?p=preview).

Comment: I don't believe you need the `p as`, since that's the default.

Comment: As a best practice, you should [always have a '.' in your ng-models](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhfUv0spHCY&feature=youtu.be&t=30m).

Comment: Well, the problem is that for the selected one you do not have extra info when dropped down... And another question: could I show this extra information as a second line with different (much smaller) font?

Comment: No, that's impossible with a standard select.